# Uploading image from flutter to firebase (nothing happens)

Tags: firebase, image, flutter, firebase-storage

I tried uploading image from flutter to firebase storage but when I try to do so nothing changes. I have made connection from firebase to flutter and when I run the code this error appears: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`. Also when I execute the code the showDialog method isn't poping off (This is a popup screen). Thanks in advance :)

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      Future <File> file;
    //final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
     openGatePhoto() async{
    final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    var reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('last_image/car5');
    await reference.putFile(file);
    //var snapshot = await storage.ref().child('last_image/car5.png').putFile(file).onComplete;
    showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CustomDialogOpen(
                  title: "Gates are open",
                  description:
                      "Licence plate numbers have been successfully stored in the database",
                ));
```

I tried fixing the code as @jitesh mentioned but still the same error, the code:

```
 final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    Reference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('last_image/car5');
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
    uploadTask.then((res) {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
            (value) => print("Done: $value"),
          );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StorageTaskSnapshot` and wait for the upload completion, the rest code is self-explanatory.

```
Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
        final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        var reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('last_image/car5');
        StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
        StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
        taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
              (value) => print("Done: $value"),
            );
      }
```

Also, it seems you haven't initialized firebase, add below code in the base widget

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUpFirebase();
  }

  void setUpFirebase() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
```

for the new `ImagePicker` API get a File like this

```
        final picker = ImagePicker();
        final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource. gallery);
        File image = new File(pickedFile.path);
```

Comment: For StorageUploadTask and StorageTaskSnapshot it displays that it want me to make a class/method

Comment: Saying error: 'StorageUploadTask' isn't a type.            
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);

Comment: you need to initialize firebase, have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: after initializing it, it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Hope it's not too late to ask a question here.
I am getting error: The argument type 'PickedFile?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File' everything is the same.
final pickedFile =...
And the error comes here
UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(pickedFile); on pickedFile

Comment: @s3v3ns: could you ask a new question for it and ping link here